Meaning of sorted samples
Say you have a finite set of samples from some distribution.
You take those samples, sort them by value from smallest to largest, and make a graph. Like this:

Horizontal axis is sorted position (arbitrary), vertical axis is sample value.
My question: what does this shape say about the distribution the samples came from? I'm tempted to say it's the inverse of the cumulative distribution function, however I can't prove it.
I know it says a lot about a distribution as I've become very accustomed to reading these graphs (because making a histogram in Excel 2007 is a pain). For example, for the image above, I can see that the underlying distribution is a bell curve with a shorter right tail and a longer left tail.

It's the inverse ECDF.

You're almost right: it would be an inverse empirical CDF (aka ECDF) provided you label the values on the horizontal axis from $0$ through $1.$

15 year mystery/suspicion solved at last <3

If your $x$ axis runs from $0$ to $1$, this is the empirical quantile function.
